# How to deal with Xamarin NuGet reference problem

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

Been messing with it for a couple of hours without luck.
I am trying to add Plugin.Badge.Droid into my project reference to start using it, but so far i have no idea why it does not work.
Getting this error message.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material`, referenced by `Plugin.Badge.Droid`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material`, or remove the reference to `Plugin.Badge.Droid`.  SherpaClean.Android

But it shows up in Android references

[image: References]

And it showed up in the project file after installation
[image]

Also adding the whole error section, just in case
[image]

Comment: Add a PackageRefenence to `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` as it suggests.

Comment: How to go about that? Thought references are the place where it needs to be in

Comment: You are already showing how you've added the other PackageReferences, just add another one

Comment: Ok, gotcha. I tried adding the material package, but it seems to me incompatible with Netstandard 2.0. Is there a workaround to this. I am a beginner to cross platform app dev with xamarin so sorry if asking dumb questions

Comment: You will have to add it to the Android project